# Get random unique regions of a list using python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers, say `list=[100,102,108,307,365,421,433,487,511,537,584]`.

I want to get unique regions from this list for example region 1 from 102-307, region 2 from 421-487 and region 3 from 511-584. These regions should be non overlapping and unique.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You seem to have a list of region boundaries and give an example where some of them have been chosen, but then say that you want "the difference between the start and end of a region should be random between 200 to 1000" which is not the case in most of your examples. Furthermore, you may need to specify what sort of randomness you care about. Different ways of selecting the boundaries may result in different random distributions in the results.

Comment: You said "but this doesn't help".   This doesn't help _what_?  What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is pick 6 elements from that list at random and sort the result (`sorted(random.sample(mylist, 6))`). Then you have a start-stop sequence with three ranges. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll credit @TimPietzcker for pointing me in the direction of this answer, although I didn't use the function he offered (`random.sample`).

In this code, I choose six indices from those in `list_` (renamed from `list` to avoid overwriting the built-in) *without replacement*, using `np.random.choice`.  I then sort these indices and iterate over each pair of adjacent indices, taking as a region the values from the first index (`i`) to the second (`j`) in the pair, *inclusive* (hence the `j + 1`).

(If I had used `j` instead of `j + 1`, the indices would never be able to include all the values in list, due to the lack of replacement during the selection phase.  For example, if one pair were `(1, 3)`, the minimum value for the first index of the next pair would be `4`, because `3` could not be chosen twice.  Thus, the first pair would take the values at indices `1` and `2`, and the value at `3` would be skipped.)

Since it's possible for `j` to be equal to `len(list_) - 1`, I've included a `try`/`except` section, which catches the `IndexError` that would be raised in this case and causes the region to include all values through the end of `list_` -- equivalent to taking the values from `i` to `j`, inclusive, as for all other cases.

```
import numpy as np


list_ = [100,102,108,307,365,421,433,487,511,537,584]
n_regions = 3
indices = sorted(np.random.choice(range(len(list_)), size=n_regions * 2,
                                  replace=False))
list_of_regions = []
for i, j in zip(indices[::2], indices[1::2]):
    try:
        list_of_regions.append(list_[i:j + 1])
    except IndexError:
        # j + 1 == len(list_), so leave it off.
        list_of_regions.append(list_[i:])
```

Comment: feel you ought to be able to use `numpy.split()` (then select 3 from result) to get list_of_regions from list_

Comment: @paddyg hmm, i don't see a way to allow holes -- i.e., some values left unselected -- using `numpy.split` (other than to randomly remove zero or more items from each "region" in the resulting split).  but thanks for introducing me to `numpy.split`.

Comment: doesn't `list_of_regions = np.split(list_, indices)[1::2]` produce the same result as your code? i.e. alternate splits are a start index or end index

Comment: @paddyg no, it doesn't.  your code makes it so certain values will always be left out (the ones that occur at a split).  you can run it to confirm this.  (i just did.)

Comment: you're right, and adding a line `indices[1::2] += 1` reduces the simplicity this method might have had (also need to change to `..np.random.choice(len(list_)-1, n_regions * 2,` to keep index in bounds)